# The quickest way to earn 50 reputation?

Tags: discussion

I need to add a comment to clarify a question that another user has added to a post of mine. I replied with a question and it got deleted and I was asked to post a new question that didnt need clarifying. I posted a new clarified question (with the info Taco Buffet had asked me in the original) and this was closed because it was answered in the previous closed one.

Comment: Are you not able to comment on [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/275009/how-can-i-search-an-excel-spreadsheet-in-sharepoint) post??

Comment: Yes I can now thank you Ganesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question does not belong to SharePoint StackExchange. You should really ask this question on [Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

However check below links. It will help you get some clarification:

[What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

[Six simple tips to get Stack Overflow reputation fast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast).